# Checking a reference with ant

Tags: ant

Is there any way to check in ant that a reference with specific refid is defined somewhere?

For example, I need to check that my.ref is defined before using it as follows.

```
<pathconvert property="my.prop" refid="my.ref">
...
</pathconvert>
```

I need to do it since in my project there are some build scripts which not under my control (actually, I am not allowed to examine their content sometimes).

These scripts are supposed to define this reference. Unfortunately, I can't count that this reference is defined due to some reason.

So, I need to check it and perform graceful error handling or some specific actions.

Is there any way to do it?

**Update:**

I found the correct way to do it myself.
It can be done by using `isreference` element of the `condition` task.

For instance:

```
<condition property="my.ref.defined">
    <isreference refid="my.ref"/>
</condition>
<fail unless="my.ref.defined" message="Reference my.ref not defined."/>
```

Comment: I would add the solution as an answer and mark it, that way everybody would see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a property based on the [value of a reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#toString), then test that property.  For example:

```
<property name="my.prop" value="${toString:my.ref}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. ${toString:my.ref} evaluates as "${toString:my.ref}" value when my.ref is not set.

Comment: @Ken - so if you find that value in the property, you know the reference was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it works with all types of references it's better to use ${ant.refid:reference}, see [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#toString), though it works with ${toString:reference} in most cases.

With [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) it's a one-liner =

```
 <project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <fl:fail message="Houston we have a problem" test="not has.property['ant.refid:my.ref']"/>
```

Flaka has also control structures like when, unless, while, for, choose, switch ..

```
 <fl:when test="not has.property['ant.refid:my.ref']">
  ...
 </fl:when>
```

[see Flaka Manual](http://flaka.googlecode.com/files/flaka.pdf)